# how to use toWei() function in web3.js for tokens having 2 decimals?

Tags: decimal, token, web3js

I am trying to convert amount in wei using web3js function called toWei().

Here is my code:

```
     var etherwithdrawamount1=web3Infura.utils.toWei(etherwithdrawamount, 'wei');
```

Now, the problem is that the token amount is not calculating correct, because the token has 2 decimals.

In web3 documentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#towei
there is no places for 2 decimals.

number - String|Number|BN: The value.

unit - String (optional, defaults to "ether"): The ether to convert
   from.

Possible units are :

> noether: ‘0’
>   wei: ‘1’
>   kwei: ‘1000’
>   Kwei: ‘1000’
>   babbage: ‘1000’
>   femtoether: ‘1000’
>   mwei: ‘1000000’
>   Mwei: ‘1000000’
>   lovelace: ‘1000000’
>   picoether: ‘1000000’
>   gwei: ‘1000000000’
>   Gwei: ‘1000000000’
>   shannon:‘1000000000’
>   nanoether: ‘1000000000’
>   nano: ‘1000000000’
>   szabo: ‘1000000000000’
>   microether: ‘1000000000000’
>   micro: ‘1000000000000’
>   finney: ‘1000000000000000’
>   milliether: ‘1000000000000000’
>   milli: ‘1000000000000000’
>   ether: ‘1000000000000000000’

So, how to get correct value in toWei() where the token decimals are 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function strtodec(amount,dec){
stringf = "";
for(var i=0;i<dec;i++){
stringf = stringf+"0";
}
return amount+stringf;
}
```

You need to call this function using this method:

```
strtodec(amount,'your token decimal here')
```

The logic is this: The function adds zeros in the amount as many as decimals you want.

Answer (score 2):

The function you are using, `toWei()`, is used to convert ether amounts in wei, not token amounts in wei. To convert token amounts in wei you have to use the token's price. More specifically you have to multiply the token amount with the token's price in wei, or any other unit for that matter, and that will tell you how much the tokens you have cost, in the unit you used above. So if you have 10 tokens and each token cost `2 wei` then you have `20 wei` worth in tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Here what i found,

```
let decimal = "1".padEnd(decimals+1,0);
let { unitMap } = web3.utils;
let unit = Object.keys(unitMap).find((k) => unitMap[k] === decimal);
let amount = web3.utils.toWei(etherwithdrawamount, unit);
```

Its too late. But it may be useful to someone.